# C: why do the character values change after the printf statement?

Tags: c, gdb, printf, character

I have the following code:

```
struct card{
   char rank;
   char suit;
};

struct hand{
   struct card top;
   struct hand* next;
};

struct player{
   struct hand* card_list;
};


int add_card(struct player* p, struct card* new_card)
{
   struct card c = {new_card->suit, new_card->rank};
   struct hand h = {c, NULL};
   p->card_list = &h;
}

int main()
{
   struct player p;
   struct card c = {'T', 'S'};
   add_card(&p, &c);
   printf("Card is: %c%c\n\n", p.card_list->top.rank, p.card_list->top.suit);
   return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the program always a garbage value whenever I try to run it.

The output is always:

**Card is: ▒**

I tried debugging it using gdb. The char values are correct until I reach the printf statement, after which they suddenly change. I don't know why that's the case.

Below is the gdb output:

```
(gdb) print p.card_list->top
$6 = {suit = 83 'S', rank = 84 'T'}
(gdb) s
78          printf("Card is: %c%c\n\n", p.card_list->top.rank, p.card_list->top.suit);
(gdb) s

Card is: ▒▒
(gdb) print p.card_list->top
$7 = {suit = -32 '\340', rank = -53 '\313'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in below line:-

```
  p->card_list = &h;
```

`h` is a local variable. Memory will get released as soon as function scope will end. Which is causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I probably should've figured it out. Oh well, thanks a ton.